# How do git hooks provide arguments on different operating systems

Tags: git

I was reading this article on Git Hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

For some of the hooks like pre-push, they supply arguments via stdin, such as the local ref. So for example, the pre-push script will supply the local ref as an input like `refs/heads/<my branch name>`.

Will these be supplied differently on Windows OS for example? E.g., `refs\heads\<my branch name>`, or will they always be supplied as forward slashes, similar to git commands.

It wasn't clear in the documentation and I don't have a windows machine so  I can't check.

Comment: It's always forward slashes. These are Git's internal strings, not file names.

Comment: @torek If you comment that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references (and hash IDs) supplied on the standard input for such hooks are in the same forward-slash format as on Linux systems—these are Git strings, not file names.